# Undo Marking Folder as Source Directory in PyCharm

Tags: python, installation, import, pycharm, packaging

So I've developed a larger package `my_package` in PyCharm and throughout the development process, I had marked the `my_package` directory as a source directory, and PyCharm automatically set up the import statements like

```
from path1.to.module import something
from path2.to.another.module import more
import path3

[Code of a module in a package that uses something and more...]
```

where `path1`, `path2` and `path3` all reside as subfolders directly under `my_package`. Now I want to install and ship my code as a package however. After installation and import to the Python shell, however, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'path1'`, because outside PyCharm's source directory magic Python would only recognize

```
from my_package.path1.to.module import something
from my_package.path2.to.another.module import more
from my_package import path3

[Code of a module in a package that uses something and more...]
```

How can I fix all my import statements in my package efficiently? I have 70+ files and by hand will be tough to do.

Answer (score 0):

So as a simple workaround, I ended up copy-pasting my code without refactoring into the project root directory.
Then, from there, in the IDE, I refactored my code into the subdirectory again, which auto-updated all import paths.